# Не могу удалить элемент объекта, созданный конструктором

Tags: javascript

Никак не получается удалить элемент объекта, созданный конструктором. 
Почему так происходит?

Код:

```js
class Product {
  constructor(name, size) {
    this.name = name;
    this.size = size;
  }

  getSize() {
    return this.size;
  }
}

class Burger extends Product {
  constructor(name, size, stuffing) {
    super(name, size);
    this.stuffing = stuffing;
  }

  getStuffing() {
    return this.stuffing;
  }
}

class Menu {
  constructor(burger, salad, drink) {
    this.burger = burger;
  }

  orderBill() {
    let burgerSizePrice =
      this.burger.getSize() === "xl"
        ? 250
        : this.burger.getSize() === "normal"
        ? 200
        : 150;


    let burgerStuffingPrice =
      this.burger.getStuffing() === "xl"
        ? 100
        : this.burger.getStuffing() === "normal"
        ? 80
        : 50;


    let result =  burgerSizePrice + burgerStuffingPrice;
    return result;
  }

  deleteProduct(product){
    delete this[product];
    return this;
  }
}

// define product
const burger = new Burger("hamburger", "small", "onion");

// adding product to order
const order = new Menu(burger);

// total bill
console.log(order.orderBill());

// remove smth from order
order.deleteProduct(burger);
console.log(order);
```

Comment: Кода слишком много. Оформи его, пожалуйста, как [mcve] (акцентирую на словах *минимальный* и *воспроизводимый*).

Comment: Вас надо понять разницу между конструкциями `obj.burger` и `obj[burger]`

Comment: Прошу прощения за оформление, первый раз задаю тут вопрос

Comment: Alexey Ten: а разве есть разница по результату?

Comment: *yar85* corrected! Было бы здорово, если бы кто-то мне помог с этим вопросом

Comment: `order.deleteProduct(burger);` - здесь `burger` является экземпляром объекта... и соотв, интерпретатор не может понять, чего ты от него хочешь передавая объект в качестве ключа (`this[product]` → `this[burger]` → `undefined`). Ясно, что задумана логика передачи как `this['burger']`, но имя переменной не превратится в строку, так это не работает.

Comment: Сейчас своей усталой башкой я могу придумать только вариант с проверками объектного типа аргумента, через `instanceof` - но это спагетти код получится. Это не гуд, потому что в реальном коде может оказаться больше трех свойств (`burger`, `salad`, `drink`). Может лучше будет через `Map` реализовать класс `Menu` (ну, в смысле унаследовать второе от первого)... у словаря объекты же могут быть ключами.

Comment: Тем более что все нужные методы у `Map` уже есть искаропки (в прототипе): хоть по ключам искать можно (метод `keys`), хоть точное вхождение проверять через `has`. Добавишь свои свойства и методы (типа `orderBill`) и т.д., и готово. М?

Comment: @yar85 Спасибо большое! Бум думать, стало намного яснее в голове))

Answer (score 0):

```
order.deleteProduct("burger");
```

или

```
deleteProduct(product){
  for (var key in this) {
    if (this[key] == product) {
      delete this[key];
      break;
    }
  }
  return this;
}
```